# Matter.js: Balls flying through circular boundary (formed by rectangular bodies) in stacked bodies

Tags: javascript, animation, physics-engine

I'm working on a project using Matter.js physics engine, and I have created a **stack of circular bodies**. The stack is enclosed within a circular boundary, which is constructed by arranging **rectangular bodies in a circular formation**. However, I'm facing an issue where **the balls tend to fly through the circular boundary** instead of colliding with it.

Here's a codepen for the project. https://codepen.io/shar8f2023/pen/YzRGqjW

```
// Set the desired timestep value
var newTimestep = 0.01; // Adjust this value as needed

// Set the runner's delta value to control the timestep
runner.delta = newTimestep;

// Start the runner
Matter.Runner.run(runner, engine);

console.log(runner.delta);
```

Could someone please help me understand why the balls are not colliding with the circular boundary (constructed by rectangular bodies) and provide guidance on how to fix this issue? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried adjusting the density of the bodies, adjusting runner timestep to 0.02 and increasing the restitution, but the issue persists. The circular boundary is formed by organizing rectangular bodies to create a circular shape. I suspect that this arrangement might be causing the problem, but I'm not sure how to resolve it.